# Change Java Swing default drag and drop action to copy

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to reverse the move and copy drag 'n drop actions in Java Swing? That is, make copy the default drag action with Ctrl-drag as move, including changing the cursor accordingly?

Comment: DnD is a complex, multiple layered API.  Which part are you talking about?  The `Transferable` layer or of the "core" layer?  If you're taking about the higher level `Transferable` layer, then you need to supply your own `TransferHandler`.  I doubt you could change the default action, as it's more complicated then just changing the "type" of operation

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a TransferHandler. Would like to switch the default move with copy and the associated cursor changes. But it might not be possible in any reasonable way. Could not find anything about that.

Comment: Take a look at [TransferHandler#getSourceActions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#getSourceActions(javax.swing.JComponent)).  This should return `TransferHandler#COPY`.  As to the mouse cursor, going WAY back to Java 6/7 there was a bug which prevented the mouse cursor from been updated (or at least customising from memory), so you might have issues with that